# For a given sequence of random variables $R_n$, what does the stochastic order relations $o_p(R_n)$ and $O_p(R_n)$ mean intuitively?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

For a given sequence of random variables $R_n$, I am wondering what the stochastic order relations $o_p(R_n)$ and $O_p(R_n)$ mean intuitively.

By definition, given a sequence of random variables $R_n$, we have that for small-oh-p the definition is:

$$
X_n = o_p(R_n) \ \ \implies \ \ X_n = Y_n R_n \ \ \text{and} \ \ Y_n \overset{\mathbb{P}}\to 0
$$

and that for big-oh-p the definition is:

$$
X_n = O_p(R_n) \ \ \implies \ \ X_n = Y_n R_n \ \ \text{and} \ \ Y_n = O_p(1)
$$

It is commonly stated that these two expresses **that the sequence $X_n$ converges in probability to zero or is bounded in probability at the "rate" $R_n$.**

I am not sure why this is so. Why do we introduce an extra term of $Y_n$ here and what is the intuition behind these implications?

Comment: It is not much different from saying $R_n/X_n$ converges in probability to zero or is bounded in probability, except that this is slightly more general since $X_n$ might vanish sometimes.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $X_n/R_n $ and $R_n $.